Differences in how %in% compares numeric data to dates - R v4.3.2
I am rerunning code produced by a coworker, and the behaviour in my instance is not what we expected. On my coworker's machine, the following logical test populates a matrix of values:
dates_match_df <- as.matrix(my_df[,i+1][my_df[,1] %in% dates_to_compare == TRUE])

In this instance,  dates_to_compare is a sequence of dates populated with the following function:
note library(zoo)
DateSeq <- function(st, en, freq) {
  st <- as.Date(as.yearmon(st)) 
  en <- as.Date(as.yearmon(en)) 
  as.Date(as.yearmon(seq(st, en, by = paste(as.character(12/freq), "months"))), frac = 1)
}

This function gives a list with example values like:
"2024-03-31" "2024-04-30" "2024-05-31"

Meanwhile, my_df[,1] is a column from an array containing numeric values relating to dates (or the number of days elapsed since a fixed date). my_df[,1] gives me values when I check it like:
19813 19843 19874

The logical comparison between these values is where our environments behave differently. Mine will not give any TRUE values, leaving the dates_match_df matrix empty, whereas my coworker's machine will have the intended behaviour, populating the matrix with all the rows where the dates match. I can get around this issue by using as.numeric(dates_to_compare) instead of dates_to_compare, but I am still curious about the problem.
Does anyone know what could be causing this difference in how our environments behave? Thanks.
I have checked to ensure we have the same packages installed. Lubridate is one that we both use, for example. I am running R v.4.3.2 while my coworker is running v4.2.2.
EDIT: Including the output of sessionInfo() as suggested by Ben Bolker.
Coworker:
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
     
    Matrix products: default
     
    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
    [5] LC_TIME=English_Ireland.utf8    
     
    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
     
    other attached packages:
    [1] xlsx_0.6.5        xts_0.13.1        zoo_1.8-12        writexl_1.4.2     scales_1.2.1      svMisc_1.2.3      stringr_1.5.0    
    [8] reshape2_1.4.4    readxl_1.4.3      plyr_1.8.9        openxlsx_4.2.5.2  mise_0.1.0        lubridate_1.9.3   ggplot2_3.4.4    
    [15] data.table_1.14.8 dplyr_1.1.3      
     
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] zip_2.3.0        Rcpp_1.0.11      pillar_1.9.0     compiler_4.2.2   cellranger_1.1.0 tools_4.2.2      lattice_0.22-5   lifecycle_1.0.4 
    [9] tibble_3.2.1     gtable_0.3.4     timechange_0.2.0 pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.1.2      cli_3.6.1        rJava_1.0-6      withr_2.5.2     
    [17] xlsxjars_0.6.1   generics_0.1.3   vctrs_0.6.4      grid_4.2.2       tidyselect_1.2.0 glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.5     
    [25] magrittr_2.0.3   colorspace_2.1-0 utf8_1.2.4       stringi_1.7.12   munsell_0.5.0   

My output:
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
    
    Matrix products: default
    
    
    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_Ireland.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Ireland.utf8   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_Ireland.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
    [5] LC_TIME=English_Ireland.utf8    
    
    time zone: Europe/Dublin
    tzcode source: internal
    
    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
    
    other attached packages:
     [1] xlsx_0.6.5        xts_0.13.2        zoo_1.8-12        writexl_1.5.0     scales_1.3.0     
     [6] svMisc_1.2.3      stringr_1.5.1     reshape2_1.4.4    readxl_1.4.3      plyr_1.8.9       
    [11] openxlsx_4.2.5.2  lubridate_1.9.3   ggplot2_3.4.4     data.table_1.15.0 dplyr_1.1.4      
    
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] gtable_0.3.4      compiler_4.3.2    tidyselect_1.2.0  Rcpp_1.0.12       zip_2.3.1        
     [6] lattice_0.21-9    R6_2.5.1          generics_0.1.3    tibble_3.2.1      munsell_0.5.0    
    [11] pillar_1.9.0      rlang_1.1.3       utf8_1.2.4        stringi_1.8.3     timechange_0.3.0 
    [16] cli_3.6.2         withr_3.0.0       magrittr_2.0.3    grid_4.3.2        rJava_1.0-11     
    [21] rstudioapi_0.15.0 lifecycle_1.0.4   vctrs_0.6.5       glue_1.7.0        cellranger_1.1.0 
    [26] xlsxjars_0.6.1    fansi_1.0.6       colorspace_2.1-0  tools_4.3.2       pkgconfig_2.0.3


Could we possibly see the results of sessionInfo() from both machines?

Verify the same revision of all libraries involved are the same.   You might also run find() to ensure there's no conflicting function names from different libraries.

Take caution in assuming data types in R when data is read in via various base and other libraries

This probably has to do with the fact that as of R4.3.0 as.Date(<numeric>) is possible without specifying the origin. You can do things like lapply(c(19813, 19843, 19874), as.Date) w/o need of lubridate.

However,  never ever roll your own date-time functions  .  I'm assuming your st and en data represent fractional years, e.g.   2021.5 is May 2021 -- so some idiot created those data sets very badly to begin with.  I'm not certain how accurate zoo is with respect to things like 12:01AM.   Convert your source data and your "elapsed days" into  Posix date format.

Has R ever shown a Date-object in a matrix? Testing in base-only, R-4.2.3 and R-4.3.2 both return 19815 in a 1x1 matrix when I do as.matrix(Sys.Date()).

@BenBolker - I have updated it with the sessionInfo().
